# VBA with selenium throws element not visible error

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Upon running my script , I get stuck with element not visible error in vba with selenium. Here is the code I was trying with:

```
Sub Table_stuff()

Dim driver As New WebDriver

With driver
    .Start "chrome", "http://apps.tga.gov.au/Prod/devices"
    .get "/daen-entry.aspx"
    .Timeouts.PageLoad = 20000
    .FindElementById("disclaimer-accept").Click
    .Timeouts.PageLoad = 20000
    .FindElementById("medicine-name").SendKeys ("pump") ''Error thrown here
    .FindElementById("medicines-header-text").Click
    .FindElementById("submit-button").Click
    .Timeouts.PageLoad = 20000
End With
End Sub
```

Here is the element reaching where my scraper throws that specific error:

```
<input type="text" name="medicine-name" id="medicine-name" value="" 
placeholder="Type at least 3 characters" title="Enter medical device name" 
autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" class="placeholder" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
```

Comment: Is the element actually visible in a browser?

Comment: Yep, element is visible in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand `Timeouts.PageLoad` call would not actually trigger selenium driver to wait - I think it just sets a page load timeout. Which means that your code would try to send keys to the search input at the moment of the opened license dialog - which triggers the "element not visible" error.

What you need is a `Wait` call (well, ideally an *Explicit Wait*, but I am not sure if VBA bindings have that functionality):

```
.Wait 3000  ''3 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing FindById with XPath to get the title, which accepts input, should work.

Here is the code snippet:

```
.FindElementByXPath("//input[@title='Enter medical device name']").SendKeys ("pump")
```